# time majority vote algorithm error

Tags: c++, algorithm

here is the algorithm http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html
and this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int ans,counter=0,a,temp=0,time=0;
    while(temp<n){
        cin>>a;
        if(counter==0)
        {
            counter=1;
            ans=a;
        }
        else if(counter>0){
            if(ans==a)
                ++counter;
            else
                --counter;
        }
        ++temp;
    }
    cout<<"The number "<<ans<<" is in the more majority ";
}
```

and my problem is
when you give 6 6 1 2 3 
it say that 3 is in the more majority

where is my problem?
thanks

Comment: Should it really say that 6 is the majority?  Majority means that more than half voted for something.  I would expect that the answer would be "no majority found."

Comment: (I'd expect the program to still be waiting for input at that point, unless a 5 was passed first.)

Comment: I assumed from context that 5 was passed in as the first parameter, and that the reference to "6 6 1 2 3" meant only during the while loop.

Comment: @atk Maybe the right change is to say "mode" instead of "majority" -- that seems to be the concept the OP is getting at. Also, in a lot of machine learning literature, this kind of thing is just colloquially called a "majority vote" algorithm, even if the determining criterion is not that there is a subset of possible outputs that received more than half of the available votes. It's generally accepted as valid terminology to call something like this a "majority vote" in that context.

Comment: how can i fix it? to say nothing found? in fact i want to find a number that repeat more than n/2 with this algorithm how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You correctly implemented the algorithm, but you didn't interpret it correctly.

The algorithm assumes there is a majority element (more than half the elements are that particular element) and returns it. If the assumption is false, you have to go through the entire sequence two times to check if there really is a majority.

In your example there is no majority and therefore the algorithm doesn't work.

Comment: we have an algorithm that not assumes "there is a majority"?

Comment: The site [explains it](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html#step13)

"In some situations you know, or assume, there is a majority element.
But if you must confirm that the chosen element is indeed the majority element, you must take one more linear pass through the data to do it."

Comment: i'm so sorry i am beginner in c++ how can i do this? can you correct my code please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the expected answer for the given data.  The key is this quote from the linked page:

> "When we are done, the current candidate is the majority element, if
>   there is a majority."

In this case, there is no majority, so the algorithm returns an invalid result.  Try again with input `6 6 6 1 2`

---

Here's an implementation with no arrays that a professor is unlikely to accept:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int majority(int n,int &ans,int counter){
  int a,i;
  if (!n) return 0;
  cin>>a;
  if (!counter) ans=a;
  counter+=2*(ans==a)-1;
  i=majority(n-1,ans,counter);
  return i+(ans==a);
}
int main(){
  int n,ans;
    cin>>n;
     if (n/2 < majority(n,ans,0))
        cout<<"The number "<<ans<<" is in the more majority "<<endl;
     else 
        cout<<"No majority"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want to say that there is no majority instead of number 3 is the majority what condition i should add?

Comment: This is correct, to confirm the candidate is a majority requires another pass through the data. The linked page states it and my answer to his previous question says it.

Comment: As @Blastfurnace says, you need another pass to count the instances of the result and confirm that there are more than `n/2` of them.

Comment: i'm sorry can you type this line in c++ ? is it possible do this without using array?i want to do this without array

Comment: if we using this code in loop it gives error for example give 7 & 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 it gives us 3

Comment: it's a recursive version of yours, which counts the number of time the answer appeared as it unwinds the stack, and checks that against n/2 before deciding what to print.